# Theme colors changed (presumably after update)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know if this has happened to anyone else, but my VSCode seems to have updated a day or two ago and the keywords that used to be highlighted green are now highlighted blue.

As a matter of fact, as soon as it opens up, it shows the "old" colors, with the green, the light blue and everything but then one second later it repaints them to the new one (with mostly blue keywords).

Has this happened to anyone? Any idea how to roll the theme back to what it was before?

It's the Dark+ (default dark) theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings, disable Semantic Highlighting.
[image: Disable Semantic Highlighting]

or set `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` in `settings.json`